# ReferenceError: angular is not defined in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webstorm

I'm completely new to AngularJS and I might have missed some crucial but not obvious step along the way of starting a new AngularJS project in WebStorm.

I installed Node.JS, installed Angular with npm, I even installed bower, I even installed angular in bower, but at this point I'm not sure what I am missing.

On Debug, I get the following message:

```
c:\Users\YourUser\WebstormProjects\angularjs-template\app\app.js:6
angular.module('myApp', [
^
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\YourUser\WebstormProjects\angularjs-template\app\app.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

On Run, I get the following message:

```
c:\Users\YourUser\WebstormProjects\angularjs-template\app\app.js:6
angular.module('myApp', [
^
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\YourUser\WebstormProjects\angularjs-template\app\app.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

App.js is the following

```
'use strict';



// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

And yes, the order of Angular in the HTML is the following:

```
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

It's funny because I'm literally just trying to run the basic template generated with WebStorm.

Run Configuration has

```
 Node Interpreter: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
 Working directory: C:\Users\YourUser\WebstormProjects\angularjs-template
 JavaScript file: app\app.js
 After launch: http://localhost:63342/angularjs-template/app/index.html
```

And nope! Angular is undefined.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Exact output

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 9.0.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" app\app.js

c:\Users\Zhuinden\WebstormProjects\angularjs-template\app\app.js:6
angular.module('myApp', [
^
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Zhuinden\WebstormProjects\angularjs-template\app\app.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Comment: Technically, I'm going to laugh if my problem was that I had to install angular with `bower install angular` with the terminal, and THEN i had to run `index.html` rather than run it as a node.js app. Does anyone know the truth?

Comment: do you see any error in console except `angular is not defined`?

Comment: @Grundy I posted it what the IDE says in an edit

Comment: possibly you need remove `JavaScript file: app\app.js` from _run configuration_

Comment: @Grundy then it says `Error: please specify path to App JS File correctly.` although I'm starting to wonder if I should really be using a Node.JS run configuration for this.

Comment: so try rename your _app.js_ with client code and add empty _app.js_

Comment: Thanks for posting - I am brand new as well (though a dev of 5 years exp) and this also through me for a loop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular code can't be run with node.js. 
Steps to start with a new Angular project in WebStorm:

1. create a new Angular project using File/New project
2. open built-in terminal, run 'npm install'
3. right-click app/index.html, choose 'Debug' - your Angular
   application will be run on WebStorm built-in server

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run app.js on node.js. I think in project template should exist server's js file for that.

Comment: Well there's a `bower.json` and a `karma.conf.js` but I'm not sure if any of them are what I need. I guess I really shouldn't be trying to run `app.js` on Node.js though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the index.html, not the app.js as usual. Algo in the root folder of the project you can run npm start and it will run up the server with the page in the port:8000